# how can i read and rewrite a matrix from another file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I try to read a matrix from another file so i can get specific values and rewrite them. Now i have a file with a matrix of 10 by 10 and i just print it. How can I get specific numbers from the matrix?

this is my code to open the matrix:

```
f = open ( 'matrix.txt' , 'r')
l = []
l = [ line.split() for line in f]
print(l)
```

this is my output:

```
[['0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,'],
['0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,'],
['0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '3,', '3,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,'],
['0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '3,', '3,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,'],
['0,', '0,', '3,', '3,', '2,', '2,', '3,', '3,', '0,', '0,'],
['0,', '0,', '3,', '3,', '2,', '2,', '3,', '3,', '0,', '0,'],
['0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '3,', '3,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,'],
['0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '3,', '3,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,'],
['0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,', '0,'],
['1,', '1,', '2,', '2,', '1,', '1,', '2,', '2,', '1,', '1,']]
```

Comment: Whats your expected out put?

Comment: i want to get the value of a specific coordinate like this:

Comment: [4], [5] = '3' or [6], [4] = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 10x10 array of strings, which you can access by

```
p = l[i][j]
```

you will get a string result, such as l[4][5] = '2,'

If you want to access the value, then you need to convert this to a number

```
p = int(l[4][5][:-1])
```

This will set p = 2